# Instance of JComboBox

Tags: java, swing, instance, jcombobox

Well i have a problems when a instance the Jcombox is not a problem of code( i think) it just that when a instance the JCombox, the buttons a i create are not visible in my Window until y resize the windows, and the they appear

```
public class ventana extends JFrame {

        static JCheckBox ch1;
    static JCheckBox ch2;
    static JCheckBox ch3;
    static ButtonGroup bg;
    static JComboBox cb;
public static void main(String[] args) {

    JFrame jf = new JFrame("asd");
    jf.setVisible(true);
    jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    jf.setSize(200,320);
    jf.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
    ch1 = new JCheckBox();
    ch2 = new JCheckBox();
    ch3 = new JCheckBox();
    String [] x= {"1","2","3"};
    cb = new JComboBox(x);
    cb.addItem("Asdd");
    cb.addActionListener(e ->{

    });
    bg = new ButtonGroup();
    bg.add(ch1);
    bg.add(ch2);
    bg.add(ch3);

    jf.add(ch1);
    jf.add(ch2);
    jf.add(ch3);
    jf.add(cb);


}
```

}

Note: I try with JPanel too and is the same problem, and with repaint() too!

Note: the app doesnt have any fuctionality, i just wanna know how to resolve the problem

UPDATE: to resolve the problem you only have to put the "jf.setVisible(true);" at the end.

Comment: Don't use static variables for you GUI components. There is no reason to do this. Start by reading the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Combo Boxes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html) for example code that is better structured.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set your JFrame to visible after you add all of your components.

This is because you are adding your components AFTER your JFrame painted to the screen (by setting visible to true) so if you set visible to true after you add the components it will paint with the components you added.

The reason it would only paint after you re-sized the window is because resizing the window causes it to paint again (and as @camickr mentioned in the comments, causes the layout manager to invoke and position the elements since you are not giving them a size).

If you want to repaint your JFrame after you set it to visible you can also use `jf.revalidate()` followed by `jf.repaint()`.

**Code:**

```
 JFrame jf = new JFrame("asd");
jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
jf.setSize(200,320);
jf.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
ch1 = new JCheckBox();
ch2 = new JCheckBox();
ch3 = new JCheckBox();
String [] x= {"1","2","3"};
cb = new JComboBox(x);
cb.addItem("Asdd");
cb.addActionListener(e ->{

});
bg = new ButtonGroup();
bg.add(ch1);
bg.add(ch2);
bg.add(ch3);

jf.add(ch1);
jf.add(ch2);
jf.add(ch3);
jf.add(cb);
jf.setVisible(true); //This is where you want to set your JFrame to visible
```

Comment: OH! Thank that works! but why happend that problems? i dont understand well!

Comment: Updated with explanation.

Comment: 1+, @Raxor, when a component is created it has a size of (0, 0), so there is nothing to paint. When you resize the frame the layout manager is invoked and the component is given a proper size and location.

Comment: @chrissukhram, if you add components to a visible GUI you need to user revalidate() and repaint().

Comment: Ok i understand that but, i mean, why happend just when i instance the JComboBox?... with the checkBox work just fine!

Comment: Oh thanks i dont knew that!, and if you can answer my question about why happend just when i instance JComboBox i will thankful

Comment: I believe it is because a JComboBox's size is changed when an item is added to it as you have done. So initially it has no "items" and when you add one its size changes and needs to be revalidated and redrawn. Whereas the check boxes are defaulted to the same size. I am not 100% sure as to the inner-workings of what causes it to behave that way but this is more of a speculation as to why it is happening.